# What are the possible philosophical inspirations for the philosophical concept of "antifragility" that was defined by Taleb?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-mathematics

It seems to me that this is just a generalization of "hormesis" by trivially  abstracting some of it's aspects but I am not very well versed in philosophy.

Comment: Building your worldview for durability goes back very early in philosophy.  The Plato's four identified virtues include Prudence, which is basically planning how not to be fragile, and Courage, which involves not accepting fragility that can be readily avoided (alongside Justice and Temperance.)  There is also a thread in 'positive' psychology of the explicit study of resilience, trying to fill out the picture sketched in by a long preoccupation with psychological and sociological failures.

Comment: Philosophy Now has an informative [review of Antifragile](https://philosophynow.org/issues/97/Antifragile_by_Nassim_Nicholas_Taleb):"*Taleb’s arguments... are best understood within his overall critique of modern rationalising... not only does he reject the Enlightenment premise that the world is knowable (much less malleable according to human desires), he is also sympathetic to ancestral traditions and religions... One of Nietzsche’s projects was the recuperation of the Dionysian spirit. This also appears to be one of the unstated objectives of Antifragile.*"

Comment: The question should include at least a basic explanation of the concept of antifragile.

Comment: Anything that "gains from disorder" is called antifragile by Taleb I suppose.